# How to improve efficiency in periodicity detection?

Tags: binary-star, pulsar, algorithm

Our [data set](https://clbin.com/C7Jcz) has $10^4$ data points, but has a long baseline and many gaps.

If we bin the data, there would be $10^8$ data points ($[t,\rm {value}]$), but only about 1% are non-zero values.

How to improve the detection efficiency?

Is a multi-threading way possible (especially for Lomb-Scargle)?

For example, if I use LombScargle in *astropy.stats*,

```
freq, power = LombScargle.autopower(minimum_frequency=0.5, maximum_frequency=1.5, normalization='standard')
```

there are two problems:

1. It is slow and easy to get `memoryError`.
2. It can't utilize the computing power as much as possible.

So my question is about the efficiency. For the data set above, what is the best method?

Comment: Question might be a better fit for [Computational Science SE](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: [Understanding the Lomb-Scargle Periodogram](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.09824) explains that technique nicely. Would you simply like to know if it can be (or has already been) written in a function particularly conducive to multi-threading? First glance of my (non-expert eyes) suggests that would be really straightforward, but rather than multithreading, I think the calculation is easy vectorized. I think you could ask a more specific, practical question about the technique here (how to set it up with your data) and a more computational question in CompSci as mentioned above.

Comment: @uhoh could you suggest some method which can improve the computing efficiency?

Comment: okay that would definitely be a good, and separate question, asked separately, in [Computational Science SE](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/). However, before you ask it, please find a way to explain *clearly* how you are doing it now. You can't ask how to improve something if you don't show your current method and state its speed. In the mean time, I will take a quick look at what you've added here :-)

Comment: @StephenG yep that makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

### AstroPy

Jake Vanderplas (Director of Open Software at the University of Washington eScience Institute) has written a Pythonic Preambulations post [Fast Lomb-Scargle Periodograms in Python](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2015/06/13/lomb-scargle-in-python/) which *by definition appears to be* a good place to start to learn how to do Lomb-Scargle Periodograms... Fast... in Python.

I have not read it yet in full, but I've found other posts of his to be extremely useful.

He starts out by explaining the implementation in [AstroPy](https://www.astropy.org/) which if you are going to be doing Astronomy, is probably a good thing to become familliar with.

### SciPy

Alternatively, there is [`scipy.signal.lombscargle`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lombscargle.html) which you can try assuming you have a current version of SciPy installed but want to try something different than AstroPy or want to compare performance or results.

### StackOverflow

I found [over 40 posts containing 'Lomb-Scargle' in Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Lomb-Scargle) which is a very good sign!

I notice that you've been active there and know how to ask well-received questions. Since your asking about speed and errors, StackOverflow is your go-to source! However, don't forget to be as clear as possible and quote all error messages and symptoms, and see if you can somehow add a short Minimum Complete and Verifiable Example or [MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366988). That's hard when your problem results from a very large dataset I know.

Comment: I upload a test data set. See that data link please. The data is a series of photon arrival times. We need to bin the data  and  then do lomb-scargle or fft. The problem is our low computing efficiency now. We need a faster method.

Comment: @questionhang thanks, that's great! I recommend two things, 1) wait for someone with specific experience to add another answer here, and 2) consider asking a separate question in StackOverflow as I discuss above. It's really great that you are so responsive to comments and questions. As you know, in SO they can come very quickly! :-)